# GORM criteria like query on string set

Tags: grails, grails-orm, criteria

I have a domain as below:

```
class Event {
  String name
  Set tags
  //.... other properties

  static hasMany = [tags: String]
}
```

Now, I want to implement an query for search for Event using a list of String. The search should support a 'like' based search. i.e if an Event has tag like 'annual meeting', then string 'meeting' should give that event as result.

Can this be achieved using GORM criteria?

Comment: Has anything been tried yet to see how far you can reach?

Comment: I took a while to search up to get something to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-869 there is no way to query a collection of value types with Hibernate (which GORM uses)

You must use HQL instead.